# Apache Redirect all to index.php with https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https, bootstrapping

I have read many answers on the subject but none is mentionning how to combine :

**redirecting all traffic to index.php** + **redirect all http to httpS**

the following works great for redirecting all to index.php :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

before I was doing this I was able to force http to https using this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I just cannot find a way to mix both, so that It would redirect all traffic to index.php using the same conditions and force https.

*** edit ***

in case somebody else gets confused like I did.

The reason why https was systematically returning a 404 when I was calling rewritten urls is because... My domain configuration file was incomplete, my website-ssl.conf was missing the **AllowOverride All** directive, this is why it was all working fine until I added the url rewriting. My non-ssl was correctly setup for url-rewriting so this is why it took me a little while to realise this was not working when https.

I have then added the necessary in my /etc/apache2website-ssl.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/exemple.com>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://exemple.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/params=$1 [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

I hope that'll help somebody.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Without even looking at your code, have you actually tried just putting all code on the same file? (Save for duplicate `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives.)

Comment: this is all in the same .htaccess yes, when I tried both I did not repeat RewriteEngine

Answer (score 3):

Just keep the https redirection rule above other rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Starkeen, that did not work for me I have tried this one and I was hoping it would do the trick too.

if I call  http://localhost/login I get the expected result, if I run it https it's giving a 404.

my ssl cert is configured correctly, if I call the real path, without trying to url-rewrite my https requests will give a response 200 as expected.

Comment: @arnaudbouchot the rule has nothing to do with https. it just redirects http  requests to https. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: It's true @Starkeen, I have digged in the apache .conf file for the secured version of this site, and it was missing the AllowOverride rule...

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php
</IfModule>
```

So in the above case, if user is going to `http` link, both(`re-write` to `https` and `forward to index.php`) will happen (i tried and its working). but if user is going to `https` directly, then you should have simple `rewriting` to `index.php` in your `default-ssl`